# how to create two forms for one model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create a form for adding in delivery costs to the system, these will later be used to form calculations on the total job price, when hours worked and quantity are used to multiply the values.

There are two aspects to delivery costs,

one is the crew install, which has a price per hour

the other is crew_breakdown, which also has price per hour

In the form the admin will only add either one at any time. Do I add these in the same field?

```
Furniture Transport & Crew Install  (these types will never change)
    Manchester Day (7am - 7pm)
...........

Furniture Transport & Crew Breakdown    
    Manchester Day (7am - 7pm)
.........
```

I am generating a scaffold to work it out first, Im unsure wether to go with

```
rails g scaffold DeliveryCosts type:string cost_per_hour:float
```

and use type as select menu, but then I have no way of differentiating as there are two types,

```
rails g scaffold DeliveryCosts crew_install:string crew_breakdown:string cost_per_hour:float
```

but then one field will always be left unpopulated, so how do you differentiate between them when it comes to adding these costs to job total cost? What are my options in this situation? Could I use select boxes to choose between crew install and crew breakdown, which then informs the rest of the form?

I suppose for clairty, what i am asking, is how to create two forms for one model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create as many forms as you wish for a model. Just add another view file with the new form.

**Example**

If there is for example a form in the file `views/my_model/_form.html.erb`, you can add another form by creating a new file `views/my_model/_another_form.html.erb`. To render the new form, use `render 'another_form'`.